# Get perimeter of pixels around centre pixel

Tags: python, opencv, trigonometry

I am attempting to get a circle of pixels around a centre pixel. Ie, just like how FAST keypoint detector works, I want to get the perimeter pixels around it given a radius. However the math escapes me, I know theoretically how I could obtain it using trigonometry. Ie, I could use a for loop and iterate at 15 degrees. I know the triangle hypotenuse length is the radius, I know the angle.

Any advice how I could obtain a perimeter of pixels around a given pixel?

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is:

```
(x-cx)**2 + (y-cy)**2 = r**2
```

where cx and cy is the center of the circle and x and y are the coordinates you want to test... Now we can iterate over x and get the y with the formula like this:

```
y = sqrt(r**2 - (x-cx)**2) + cy
```

The other way will be to iterate the 360 degrees and calculate the x and y and add the offset (center) like this:

```
x = cos(radians) * radius + cx
y = sin(radians) * radius + cy
```

The second version gave me a more complete circle in my tests. Here is my test script in python:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

img = np.zeros((480, 640, 1), dtype="uint8")
img2 = np.zeros((480, 640, 1), dtype="uint8")

center = (200, 200)
radius = 100

x = np.arange(center[0] - radius, center[0]+radius+1)
y_off = np.sqrt(radius**2 - (x - center[0]) **2)
y1 = np.int32(np.round(center[1] + y_off))
y2 = np.int32(np.round(center[1] - y_off))
img[y1, x] = 255
img[y2, x] = 255


degrees = np.arange(360)
x = np.int32(np.round(np.cos(degrees) * radius)) + center[0]
y = np.int32(np.round(np.sin(degrees) * radius)) + center[1]
img2[y,x] = 255


cv2.imshow("First method", img)
cv2.imshow("Second method", img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and the results are these:

**Method 1**

[image]

**Method 2**

[image]

There is a third method... You take a box around the circle of size radius x radius and evaluate each point with the circle formula given above, if it is true then it is a circle point... however that is good to draw the whole circle, since you have integers and highly probable not many point will be equal...

---

**UPDATE:**

Just a small reminder, make sure your points are in the image, in the example above, if you put the center in 0,0 it will draw 1/4 of a circle in every corner, because it considers the negative values to start from the end of the array.

To remove duplicates you can try the following code:

```
c = np.unique(np.array(list(zip(y,x))), axis=0  )
img2[c[:,0], c[:,1]] = 255
```

Comment: Both functions could be vectorized pretty easily. The second one in particular---just replace the `math` functions with `numpy` functions and use an array for `d`. You can directly index the image with the two pairs of corresponding arrays for the x and y coordinates (after rounding and explicitly casting to an int).

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds true, I will edit them in a moment

Comment: @api55 Thanks, your second solution works great. It does however always spit out 360 points even if the number of points around the centre is less than 360. For example a radius of 1, it produces 360 points instead of 4 or 8. Do you know how I could determine the angle step size? Ie, if the radius is 1 the step size would be 45 or 90.

Comment: @api55 maybe the following is correct? Instead of `for d in range(360):` it would be `for d in range(0, 360, math.floor(360 / (radius * 4))):` replace `4` for `8` depending.

Comment: @JakeM the thing is that a lot of the points will be the same... you can always filter duplicates. But maybe you can do something like to divide by the radius * 4, but put a mask to it

Comment: I think the fact that the number of points being less than 360 is not really so much a problem as you can just filter duplicates, but the bigger problem is for larger circles, this would have holes. Also @JakeM that fix isn't great IMO as degrees on a circle don't actually map to integer pixel locations...so it's just setting you up for possible holes or other problems.

Comment: @JakeM I modify it to use numpy functions (faster than loop) and added a way to delete duplicates... But maybe as @ AlexanderReynolds says, it may be better with the method using the circle from OpenCV which handles every case rather than this, which may have holes if the resolution (step size of the degrees) is not small enough

Comment: IMHO you'd really need to implement something like Bresenham's circle algorithm to get it right at all scales.

Answer (score 2):

Just draw the circle onto a mask:

```
In [27]: mask = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype=np.uint8)

In [28]: cv2.circle(mask, center=(4, 4), radius=4, color=255, thickness=1)
Out[28]:
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255, 255,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255, 255,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

And now you can use it to index your image as you like. E.g., here's a random image:

```
In [33]: img
Out[33]:
array([[ 88, 239, 212, 160,  89,  85, 249, 242,  88],
       [ 47, 230, 206, 206,  63, 143, 152,  67,  58],
       [162, 212,   0, 213, 208, 169, 228,  14, 229],
       [230,  45, 103, 201, 188, 231,  80, 122, 131],
       [159,  31, 148, 158,  73, 215, 152, 158, 235],
       [213, 177, 148, 237,  92, 115, 152, 188, 223],
       [234,  67, 141, 173,  14,  18, 242, 208, 147],
       [ 53, 194, 229, 141,  37, 215, 230, 167,  82],
       [ 72,  78, 152,  76, 230, 128, 137,  25, 168]], dtype=uint8)
```

Here's the values on the perimeter:

```
In [34]: img[np.nonzero(mask)]
Out[34]:
array([ 89, 206, 206, 143, 152, 212,  14,  45, 122, 159, 235, 177, 188,
        67, 208, 229, 141, 215, 230, 230], dtype=uint8)
```

Setting the value of the image at the perimeter of the circle to 0:

```
In [35]: img[np.nonzero(mask)] = 0

In [36]: img
Out[36]:
array([[ 88, 239, 212, 160,   0,  85, 249, 242,  88],
       [ 47, 230,   0,   0,  63,   0,   0,  67,  58],
       [162,   0,   0, 213, 208, 169, 228,   0, 229],
       [230,   0, 103, 201, 188, 231,  80,   0, 131],
       [  0,  31, 148, 158,  73, 215, 152, 158,   0],
       [213,   0, 148, 237,  92, 115, 152,   0, 223],
       [234,   0, 141, 173,  14,  18, 242,   0, 147],
       [ 53, 194,   0,   0,  37,   0,   0, 167,  82],
       [ 72,  78, 152,  76,   0, 128, 137,  25, 168]], dtype=uint8)
```

You can easily get the coordinates as well:

```
In [56]: np.where(mask)
Out[56]:
(array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8]),
 array([4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 7, 1, 7, 0, 8, 1, 7, 1, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4]))
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the pragmatic approach. :)

Answer (score -1):

Assume `img` is your image, `radius` is the radius of the circle and `x, y` are the coordinates of the center around which you want to focus.

The the `focus_img` can be obtained using

```
offset = math.ceil(radius * math.sqrt(2))
focus_img = img[y-offset:y+offset, x-offset:x+offset]
```

Comment: OP is asking for the perimeter pixels on the edge of the circle, not an ROI centered around the circle.